# What's the difference between 1..5, [*1..5] and [1..5] in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, range

In Groovy,what is the difference between,

```
def a=1..5
def b= [*1..5]
def c=[1..5]
```

what does `*` in `[*1..5]` symbolize?

Comment: Will it be possible now to accept an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 10):

`*` represents a [Spread Operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator). Elaborating your example:

```
a = 1..5
b = [*1..5]
c = [1..5]

assert a.class.name == "groovy.lang.IntRange" //Is a range from 1 till 5
assert b.class.name == "java.util.ArrayList" //Spread the range in a list
assert c.class.name == "java.util.ArrayList" //Is a list
```

Extending @ataylor's explanation:

```
assert a.size() == 5
assert b.size() == 5
assert c.size() == 1
```

To reach each element in `c` you have to iterate over it (which is a range)

```
c.each{println it}
```

[Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html) by Mr Haki has a detailed example of its usage.

Answer (score 6):

When you put a range object in a list, you get a list with one element of type `IntRange`:

```
assert [1..5].size() == 1
```

By applying the spread operator it expands the range and you get a list with five elements, the actual integers the range represents:

```
assert [*1..5].size() == 5
```

Comment: Clear and precise! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here `*` (spread operator) expands the range `1..5` and hence you get a list of integers in that range `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`